# MQTT for Web Application

Tags: javascript, mqtt

I was trying to develop a simple web application using the MQTT Broker. I used Mosca as the broker on localhost. First I tried out a program copied from the web to see how MQTT works. This is the program.

home.html

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
  <script src="mqttws31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="client.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init();">
  </body>
</html>
```

client.js

```
var wsbroker = "127.0.0.1";  //mqtt websocket enabled broker
    var wsport = 3000 // port for above
    var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(wsbroker, wsport,
        "myclientid_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));
    client.onConnectionLost = function (responseObject) {
      alert("connection lost: " + responseObject.errorMessage);
    };
    client.onMessageArrived = function (message) {
      alert(message);//.destinationName, ' -- ', message.payloadString);
    };
    var options = {
      timeout: 3,
      onSuccess: function () {
        alert("mqtt connected");
        // Connection succeeded; subscribe to our topic, you can add multile lines of these
        client.subscribe('temp/random', {qos: 1});

        //use the below if you want to publish to a topic on connect
        message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("Hello");
        message.destinationName = "/World";
        client.send(message);

      },
      onFailure: function (message) {
        alert("Connection failed: " + message.errorMessage);
      }
    };
  function init() {
      client.connect(options);
  }
```

This program worked when I tried to access home.html in te web browser. I could see the log being generated in Mosca's console too. However, as visible, this program wasn't a very neat example. For that reason I tried to make a few changes to make the code readable.

This is my code after I made the changes -

home.html

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
  <script src="mqttws31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="client.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init();">
  </body>
</html>
```

client.js

```
var wsbroker = "127.0.0.1";
var wsport = 3000

var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(wsbroker, wsport,"myclientid_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));

    function onMessageArrived(message) {
        document.write(message.payload);
    };

    function onSuccess() {
        document.write("Connected");
        client.subscribe('temp/random');
    };

    function onFailure(message) {
        document.write("Connection Failed. Error : " + message.errorMessage);
    };

    function onConnectionLost(message) {
        document.write("Connection Lost. Error : " + message.errorMessage);
    };

    var options = {
        timeout: 3,
        onSuccess: onSuccess,
        onFailure = onFailure
    };

  function init() {
      client.connect(options);
      client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived,
      client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost,

  };
```

I have got a Python script running which publishes value. However, no output is being generated. I checked the Mosca console and noted that no new connections were made. I have just started learning Javascript. I am not sure if my new code is syntactically correct.

Comment: Two quick questions: 1. `wsport` (line 2) should have a semicolon. 2. Is there a reason you have indented the functions below `var client` and before function `init()`, when they are not within a block?

Comment: 1. I added the semicolon. Doesn;t help though. 2. No particular reason for the indentation.

Comment: From the [docs](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/jsdoc/symbols/Paho.MQTT.Client.html#connect) It suggests that `onConnectionLost` and `onMessageArrived` do not appear to be accepted by the `connect` method - I can't see them in the accepted parameters. Not sure if that would solve your issue, but seems potentially pertinent. Also from the [official example](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/) they set the callback handlers as a separate process to the connect call.

Comment: I made the required changes. Makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Couple changes will fix this.

First, you have `onFailure =` instead of `onFailure:`

Next, you want to set your `client.onMessageArrived` and `client.onConnectionLost` before you call connect, not after.

Those 2 changes result in

```
var wsbroker = "127.0.0.1";
var wsport = 3000

var client = new Paho.MQTT.Client(wsbroker, wsport,"myclientid_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));

    function onMessageArrived(message) {
        document.write(message.payload);
    };

    function onSuccess() {
        document.write("Connected");
        client.subscribe('temp/random');
    };

    function onFailure(message) {
        document.write("Connection Failed. Error : " + message.errorMessage);
    };

    function onConnectionLost(message) {
        document.write("Connection Lost. Error : " + message.errorMessage);
    };

    var options = {
        timeout: 3,
        onSuccess: onSuccess,
        onFailure: onFailure,
    };

  function init() {
    console.log('connecting')
      client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived,
      client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost,
      client.connect(options);

  };
```